# How to stop a generator once target is matched?

Tags: python, random, generator

Attempting to create a generator that generates a random set of numbers in a specified range and then stops once a specified target number is generated. The number of attempts to get to that number would be printed. If the number is not generated within the specified number of attempts, the user would get a separate prompt. Here's what I have so far:

```
try:
    min_value = int(input("Enter the minimum value for your random generator: "))
    max_value = int(input("Enter the maximum value for your random generator: "))
    target = int(input("Enter the target value you are trying to find: "))
    max_attempts = int(input("Enter the maximum number of attempts to find the target before stopping generation: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter an integer value for your input!")

def find_target(target: int, min_value: int, max_value: int, max_attempts: int) -> Optional[int]:
    # Start counter for number of attempts
    j = 0
    while j in range(max_attempts):
        #Increment the attempts counter
        j += 1
        for k in range(min_value, max_value):
            if not target:
                yield k

gen = find_target(target, min_value, max_value, max_attempts)

while True:
    print(next(gen))
```

Once the target was found, ideally something like this would happen:

```
# Stop the generator
print("Target acquired! It only took ", j, "tries to find the target!")
gen.close()

if find_target(target, min_value, max_value, max_attempts) is None:
    print("Could not find target within the max number of attempts. Maybe better luck next time?")
```

Right now the generator just stops immediately (I'm guessing it has something to do with how `if not target` is specified). How could I get the logic for this to work?

Comment: Not what is asked for, but I don't see anything random in the posted code. `range` is a sequence generator if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return target you just put yield after if statement.

```py
import random

def gen(low, high, attempts, target):
    for j in range(1, attempts+1):
        guess = random.randint(low, high)
        yield guess
        if guess == target:
            print()
            print("Target acquired! It only took ", j, "tries to find the target!")
            break
    else:
        print()
        print("Could not find target within the max number of attempts. Maybe better luck next time?")

low, high = 0, 10
attempts = 10
target = 5

for el in gen(low, high, attempts, target):
    print(el, end=' ')
```

Outputs:

```
7 0 0 3 3 5 
Target acquired! It only took  6 tries to find the target!

#or

4 2 0 6 1 4 3 6 1 6 
Could not find target within the max number of attempts. Maybe better luck next time?
```

Comment: I was able to fix the errors, but now it prints the `Could not find target` message after every single generated value. How could I get it to only print at the end? The numbers are printed vertically in the console rather than horizontally in your code

Comment: D'oh I had the `else` indented improperly, got it to work, thank you so much for your help!